# Can someone explain this Laplace Transform?

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

Why is the inverse Laplace Transform of $$\frac{\sinh(x\sqrt{s})}{ s\cdot \sinh{\sqrt{s}}}$$ equal to $$ x + \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{-(n\pi)^2t}\sin{n\pi x} ?$$

Any help would be great, totally confused.

Comment: Use residue theorem .

Comment: Can you explain how one would use it?

Comment: Consider the bronwich integral where we inclose all the poles. It is cleat that  $s= -(n \pi)^2$  are poles of order 1 for non zero integers.  For $s=0$ you need to see the Laurent expansion.

Comment: I'm still confused. How are $-(n\pi)^2$ the poles? The poles occur at $s=0$. $e^{st}$ doesn't have any poles. Can you please clarify a bit further?

Comment: I actually figured out how they're poles, but I'm stuck on getting the residues. Any help?

Comment: Hope the answer clears any doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the poles of

$$F(s) = \frac{\sinh(x\sqrt{s})}{ s\cdot \sinh{\sqrt{s}}} e^{st}$$

First we need to see if $s =0$ is a branch point or not

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s}\left( \frac{(x\sqrt{s})+(x\sqrt{s})^3/3!+\cdots}{(\sqrt{s})+(\sqrt{s})^3/3!+\cdots} \right) \left(1+(st)+\frac{(st)^2}{2!} + O(s^3)\right)$$

$$F(s) = \frac{x}{s} \left( \frac{1+x^2s/3!+\cdots}{1+s/3!+\cdots} \right) \left(1+(st)+\frac{(st)^2}{2!} + O(s^3)\right)$$

Hence we see that $s=0$ is a pole of order 1 with residue $x$. Now consider the other poles where the deliminator $\sinh(\sqrt{s})$ has zeros when $\sqrt{s} = n\pi i$ hence $s = -(n\pi)^2$ are the poles.

$$\sum_{s_0}\mathrm{Res}(F,s_0)= x+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{Res}(F,-(n\pi)^2)$$

$$\mathrm{Res}(F,-(n\pi)^2) = \lim_{s \to -(n\pi)^2} (s+(n\pi)^2) \frac{\sinh(x\sqrt{s})}{ s\cdot \sinh{\sqrt{s}}} e^{st} = 2 \lim_{s \to -(n\pi)^2} (s+(n\pi)^2) \frac{\sinh(x\sqrt{s})}{ \sqrt{s}\cdot \cosh{\sqrt{s}}} e^{st}$$

$$\mathrm{Res}(F,-(n\pi)^2)  = \frac{i \sin(n \pi x)}{ i (n\pi) \cdot \cos{(n\pi)}} e^{-(n\pi)^2 t} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n \pi }\sin(n \pi x) e^{-(n\pi)^2 t} $$

Collecting the results together we have

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(f(s)) = x + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n \pi }\sin(n \pi x) e^{-(n\pi)^2 t} $$

Comment: Great, thanks. If it's not too much to ask, I have one more question. Trying to invert that same thing above with an $e^{-L\sqrt{s}}$ multiplying it, where $L$ is a constant. How would one deal with that? I know you can use convolution but I'm having trouble with computing the integral. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I know you can invert $e^{-L\sqrt{s}}$ easily, but like I said, the convolution integral is difficult.

Comment: @Sorey, Well, that one will be difficult using residues because of the branch point.

Comment: Can you explain? I was able to get the residues without much issue but maybe I am making a mistake without knowing it. The poles are still the same, but which one causes an issue?

Comment: @Sorey, $e^{-\sqrt{s}L}$ has a branch point at $s=0$ hence when we integrate we have to indent at zero and choose a suitable branch.

Comment: Sounds over my head. Guess I'll just leave it for now. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Would you mind helping me find the residue at $s=0$? Thanks.

Comment: @Sorey, I suggest you post it as another problem. If I have time I will see what I can do. Also others might have an easier approach for that problem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164660/inverse-laplace-transform-bromwich-integral

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad
{1 \over \sinh\pars{\root{s}}} = {1 \over \root{s}} +
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\color{#f00}{\root{s} \over s + n^{2}\pi^{2}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\sinh\pars{x\root{s}} \over s}\,\color{#f00}{\root{s} \over s + n^{2}\pi^{2}}\,
\exp\pars{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\sinh\pars{x\root{-s}\ic} \over s}\,{\root{-s}\ic \over
s + n^{2}\pi^{2} + \ic 0^{+}}\,\exp\pars{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & -
\int_{0}^{-\infty}{\sinh\pars{-x\root{-s}\ic} \over s}\,{-\root{-s}\ic \over
s + n^{2}\pi^{2} - \ic 0^{+}}\,\exp\pars{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[1cm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x\root{s}} \over s}\,{\root{s} \over
s - n^{2}\pi^{2} - \ic 0^{+}}\,\exp\pars{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & -
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x\root{s}} \over s}\,{\root{s} \over
s - n^{2}\pi^{2} + \ic 0^{+}}\,\exp\pars{-ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[1cm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x\root{s}} \over \root{s}}\overbrace{\bracks{%
{1 \over s - n^{2}\pi^{2} - \ic 0^{+}} -
{1 \over s - n^{2}\pi^{2} + \ic 0^{+}}}}
^{\ds{2\pi\ic\,\delta\pars{s - n^{2}\pi^{2}}}}\,\exp\pars{-ts}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{\sin\pars{n\pi x} \over n\pi}\expo{-n^{2}\pi^{2}t}}}\qquad\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{note that}\
\lim_{n \to 0}\bracks{{\sin\pars{n\pi x} \over n\pi}\expo{-n^{2}\pi^{2}t}} = \color{#f00}{x}~}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:
$$
\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\sinh\pars{x\root{s}} \over s\sinh\pars{\root{s}}}\,
\exp\pars{ts}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} =
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{x + {2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{n\pi x} \over n}
\,\exp\pars{-\bracks{n\pi}^{2}t}}}
$$